# Android: Stop a new thread once a fragment is stopped

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments

I have a `Fragment` in which I am running an animation code in run method of a new `Thread`. Since the thread runs for too long, I want to stop it when user moves away from the fragment, by pressing back button or clicking on the other menu item.

I tried using thread.stop, thread.destroy, wait, suspend, etc in the `onPause()` method but nothing is helping, it says the `UnsupportedOperation` or Object is not locked. And crashing the app.

The reason for this requirement is if I don't kill the thread, then when trying to exit from the app it does not close the app gracefully and crashes on pressing the back button multiple times.

Please suggest a good way to start and kill a thread on creation and switching of fragment respectively.

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

private Thread mAnimationThread;
public SearchFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_anim, container, false);

    mAnimationThread = new Thread() {

        //some code here
    };

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   Log.d("anim", "in resume");
   Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext() , "Resumed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   mAnimationThread.start();
}   @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("anim", "in pause");
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Paused",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        mAnimationThread.suspend();

}}
```

Comment: Better use boolean value to stop the thread.

Answer (score 2):

See to this sample code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new MyThread());
        thread.start();
        Thread.sleep(5);
        thread.interrupt();
    }
}

class MyThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            System.out.println("Working.");
        }
        System.out.println("Interrupted.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.stop()` is highly discouraged since a time as it might terminate your `Thread` in an unsafe way (which you're probably experiencing). Probably the best way you can achieve this is  having a `boolean` controller within your `Thread`, so while it is `true`, you'd keep processing the loading, and once it gets `false` (which you would control with your `Fragment` callback), it would `return` from the `Thread` and it just stops loading.

```
boolean doRun = true;

new Thread(
  new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      while (doRun) {
        // Do whatever you need, and once this variable gets false, the Thread would exit
        ...
      }
    }
  }).start();
```

Comment: Thanks about this info. I will keep it my mind about not stopping thread. But as per your code, whenever you use an inner class like this, the outer variable should be final. I think it should be better to use a variable inside which can be modified by a simple close() method. Am I right?

Comment: You're right about the variable needs to be final. But even if you can declare an inner variable, sometimes you'll need to set it outer because your `Thread` execution will depend on certain external factors that you cannot just control with an inner `boolean`. However, setting it as final will make it a just one-assignation variable, which won't help you. A way to get rid of this is defining it as a non-primitive variable (a `Boolean[]`, for instance, and set it as `= new Boolean(1)`. This way, you can work with `myArray[0]` and you can assign it as many times as you want, even being final.

Comment: Yes this should be possible. Thanks a lot. Meanwhile I worked around it and right now, I took an inner class with a close() method and overriden it to use my custom logic in its run method. Now calling the close method in the OnDetach() method is allowing it to run properly.

Comment: While you don't use any deprecated method in the reference page (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) it should be ok. Once you've solved your issue, both for reputation and feedback, you should accept the answer that helped you most.

Answer (score 0):

override the on backpressed method and stop the thread there only.